# Configuring pudb UI

Tags: pudb

When I start up pudb, it becomes a useable mess.
Most of the windows are ten-twenty characters big.
Every window is scrunched up against the left.
Even  the help window is all scrunched up and so unreadable.

How can I adjust these parameters?
The distro is Linux Mint.

Comment: If you type "?" it will show you a menu with all keybinds. If I'm not mistaken, the keys "[" and "]" adjust a section (ex: variables) relative size. The keys "+" and "-" can also be used. If you could provide a screenshot, we would have a better understanding of what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Mint has problems with default fonts for Terminal. Pudb has user interface with windows created from characters so it relies on a terminal font which is not a proportional one. You need a font like monospace or courier. You have probably the same behavior for other console programs with this type of GUI, e.g. Midnight Commander so it's not pudb specific. See this: http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=90&t=136496